# Why is a single line in this table of contents not a link (tex4ebook on Kindle)

Tags: table-of-contents, htlatex, tex4ebook

It's not clear if the issue here is with tex or with Amazon; however I think it should be at least asked here in case anyone else finds it by Googling.

I am writing an ebook using tex4ebook.  I have the following MCVE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{fine}
\section{fine}

%##########
\chapter{5}

\fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{
  \begin{itemize}
  \item B
  \end{itemize}
 C
}}

\section{Not working}

\chapter{fine}
\section{fine}
\end{document}
```

I run tex4ebook on it and get mcve.epub. You can see the file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/onthi06plmzlgau9q6vyi/mcve.epub?rlkey=p6s6lccws9o6il4pli61wpcbp&dl=0)

When viewed in any ebook-viewer except Amazon's Kindle (online version, phone version, desktop version and ipad version) it appears fine:

[image]

However, on any of the Amazon-type e-readers the table of contents has no link to one of the sections:

[image]

My questions are:

- Why is this happening and how do I stop it?
- Can anyone reproduce this problem?

EDIT:

to make this more infuriating (and more of an Amazon problem than a LaTeX one) - the Kindle Preview software can clearly see the structure of the table of contents, it just isn't displaying it:
[image]

Comment: well you get a latex error if you compile that. You can't put a list inside an \fbox. And after a latex error the output is no longer reliable.

Comment: @hmmm.  let me see what I've done one sec...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer apologies - fixed - not quite sure how that happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get an warning when I compile this file:

```
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: samplech2.html
[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of samplech2.html failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: /home/mint/texmf/scripts/lua/LuaXML/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/div) [char=935]
```

This means that the generated Epub contains non-valid HTML code, which may cause some issues. The problematic file contains your subsection 2.1, so it is possible that it causes the issue on Kindle.

You can fix the problem with this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
  \Configure{fbox}
     {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\EndP
               \HCode{<div class="fbox">}%
               \def\end:bx{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}\par}%
      \else
               \HCode{<span class="fbox">}%
               \def\end:bx{\HCode{</span>}}%
      \fi}
     {\end:bx}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It is a modification of the original configuration from TeX4ht, which correctly closes the paragraph before end of `\fbox`. With this change, you should get a correct file.

Comment: This fixes the error message, produces a correct example, and also completely fixes the overall error in the large manuscript I was editing.  Excellent work.

Comment: @Joe that's good to hear! I've udpated TeX4ht sources, so this fix should be soon included in TeX Live.